# Changing the UI/UX of the Authentication package

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I used the AWS Authentication package in Flutter, but I want to change the UI/UX. How do I alter the custom sign-in, sign-up, forgot password and sign-out forms in the package?

Comment: From what I remember, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it because the pre-defined UI is set. The best thing you could do is to create your own screen or view their code and edit it a bit.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at their docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#authentication-with-amplify

Comment: Probably best to do that. Thank you @CoderUni